# Javascript: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error on this line in my javascript. What is wrong?

```
    // Determine if at least one element in the object matches a truth test.
  // Delegates to **ECMAScript 5**'s native `some` if available.
  // Aliased as `any`.
  var any = _.some = _.any = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    iterator || (iterator = _.identity);
    var result = false;
    if (obj == null) return result;
    if (nativeSome && obj.some === nativeSome) return obj.some(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (result || (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
    });
    return !!result;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite self-explanatory. The `||` operator produces an expression, not a statement (assignment) or function call.

Your code should work if you make it an assignment:

```
iterator = iterator || _.identity;
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out what was wrong. New to Javascript. However, now i'm getting an error on this code: computed >= result.computed && (result = {value : value, computed : computed});

Comment: There you should be using an if statement: `if ( computed >= result.computed) {result = {value : value, computed : computed}}`

Comment: The last code you sent says I'm missing a semicolon

Comment: So add the semicolon. They're not strictly required though anyways.

Comment: Sorry, not sure where the colon goes.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably getting something like this
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

In any case, you can't assign in the *OR* statement.

```
CASE IN POINT

var num = null;

num || num = 5;

=> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment;
```

Instead do this,

```
iterator || _.identity;
```

Or this

```
iterator = iterator || _.identity;
```